# object property from getPageInfo

Tags: javascript, cti

Is the `object` property, from the calls to `getPageInfo`, a key to the type of the object represented? Meaning is it fixed, despite localization?

Here's the 2 flavors of `getPageInfo`:

- [Classic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_getpageinfo.htm)
- [Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getpageinfo.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In my testing both of those methods will return both values, but the object value is in English. For example if your language is French and you get Account details, it will have displayName as Compte which is French for Account. The object field will be in English.

```
Object {objectId: "001xx000003DGZj", objectName: "Acme", object: "Account", displayName: "Compte", url: "xxx/001xx000003DGZj"}
```